# Why is the new firebase dynamic link format not being recognized in `appdelegate.m`?

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I was previously using firebase dynamic links of the format `app.goo.gl/`. They have worked very well for deep linking my `react native` ios app.

However, recently when I added `app.page.link/` type of link, it is not being detected inside the appdelegate file, where I added the function to resolve the dynamiclink.

I have added the dynamic link in the `associated domains` correctly, and I also checked the `apple-app-site-association` file for any errors and there were none.

I am sure that there is no error with the config itself as within react native if I use `Linking.getInitialUrl` and try to manually call the firebase to parse the link, it works.

But I cannot always use this method as the native module doesn't recognise it as a dynamic link.

I checked by giving NSLog to see what is being returned and it is returning false from the native module handler.

`

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application
    continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
      restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
    {
      BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks]
                      handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                      completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if (!error) {
                         [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:dynamicLink.url sourceApplication:nil annotation:nil];
                        }
                      }];

      return handled;
    }
```

`

This is the code that I have in appdelegate to handle firebase dynamic links